# Как взаимодействуют function-wrapper и потом вызываются?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Разбираюсь с данным проектом:
[rsa-aes-client-server-encryption-nodejs-example](https://github.com/weblab-technology/rsa-aes-client-server-encryption-nodejs-example)
и не могу понять, как взаимодействуют между собой обертки функций (rsa-wrapper, aes-wrapper) и как потом они вызываются? можно ссылки(у) на ресурс(ы), где можно прочитать про данный прием, или пример небольшой, любая информация приветствуется.

Comment: что за врапперы? какой _"прием"_ имеется ввиду?

Comment: @Grundy Прием оборачивания функций: файл static\js\rsa-wrapper.js является дополнением (модулем) файла components\rsa-wrapper.js? если да то как они взаимодействуют или как вызывается один из другого? или же они являются независимыми файлами?